# Redundant IRQ clear-pending operation

Tags: c, arm, interrupt, interrupt-handling, cortex-m

I am working on a project with `ARM Cortex-M0` processor. In this project I need to provide timers support (`CMSDK (SSE-200)` timers).

So, in the vector table, in the proper entry represented by `TIMER0_IRQn` we placed our handler `timer0_irq_handler`, which contains the following code:

```
void timer0_irq_handler(void)
{
    NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ(TIMER0_IRQn)
    my_timer_irq_handler(TIMER0)
}
```

My question is whether or not the call to `NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ` is needed, because from [Cortex-M0 Devices Generic User Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0497a/BABBGBEC.html):

> A pending interrupt remains pending until one of the following:
>
> **The processor enters the ISR for the interrupt. This changes the state
>   of the interrupt from pending to active**.

To my understanding, it means that the interrupt pending state is cleared automatically when we enter our ISR, and probably the call to `NVIC_ClearPendingIRQ` is redundant. Is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is cleared automatically.
You can check if it is pending, with `NVIC_GetPendingIRQ()`.